# Spring injection of Service within another Service

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, javabeans

I have two Services and a Controller that I am trying to set up, like this:

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

   @Autowired
   IMyService1 service;
}
```

Service 2:

```
@Service
public class MyService2 implements IMyService2 {   }
```

Service 1:

```
@Service
public class MyService1 implements IMyService1 {

   @Autowired
   IMyService2 myService2;  // this bean is not getting created
}
```

Everything is set up correctly in beans.xml to pick up the Components in the component scan, and everything is under the same base package.

The first service is properly injected into the Controller class, but the second service is failing to be injected (BeanCreationException) into the first Service.

Has anyone run into this or any ideas/suggestions on what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Have your tried @Resource(name = "myService2") instead of @Autowired?

Comment: have you tried to get your MyService2 through contex.getBean(MyService2.class)? Does it return your service or throws and exception?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on the subject, but I couldn't find an answer that solved this problem and I was only able instantiating the second service dynamically without `@Service` annotation.

**Controller:** Don't touch, it's the same

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
   @Autowired
   IMyService1 service;
}
```

**Service 2:** Remove `@Service` from the second service

```
public class MyService2 implements IMyService2 {
    public void doSomething() {
        // your code
    }
}
```

**Service 1:** Remove `@Autowired` and dynamically instantiate your second service

```
@Service
public class MyService1 implements IMyService1 {
   public void actionWithService2() {
       new MyService2().doSomething();
   }
}
```